# What's the best way to update multiple unique rows of a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rows

I have a list of items in a MySQL table.
The user is able to order these items by dragging them up and down in a HTML list.
I then need to store each items position in the list.

Is it possible to do this in one MySQL call or does it have to be a seperate call for each product to set its own order ID?

A single call would look something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET `order` = order_number AND `product_id` = 'X';
```

Comment: So exactly what is the question.  If you wanted to update Many unique rows you'd have to change the WHERE clause no?  So what makes it unique ?

Comment: Each row in the table is a unique product with a unique ID... each order attribute of the product is also unique - that's to say no two products can have the same `order` number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could drop the whole table and then insert the new order numbers for all products. That's only two statements. This would work as long as this table only contains the "order" information and no other critical data.

Comment: I'm aware of this method... but was wondering whether there might have been any better solutions which don't involve the deletion of data, particular for scenarios where data could not be delete for foreign key constraints, in which case I guess the solution would be to create another table of just product IDs and their order number.

Comment: I have created a seperate table which just holds the product ID and the the display order number. Then I clear the table and re-populate as you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete all items in question, and insert them back again if no other data would be affected by that (CASCADE and similar). That would be two queries; DELETE with "WHERE product_id IN ('X', 'Y', ...)", and INSERT with updated values for each item.

A clean solution would be to do an UPDATE within a transaction, but as MySQL doesn't support deferred constraint checking, you would have a problem there if the 'order' attribute is UNIQUE.